# What is the proper way to store friendship associations in a mysql DB

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, one-to-many

I want to create a table where my users can associate a friendship between one another. Which at the same time this table will work in conjunction to what I would to be a one-to-many relation between various other tables I am attempting to work up.

Right now I am thinking of something like this

member_id, friend_id, active, date

member_id would be the column of the user making the call, friend_id would be the column of the friend they are attempting to tie to, active would be a toggle of sorts 0 = pending, 1 = active, date would just be a logged date of the last activity on that particular row.

Now my confusion is if I were to query I would typically query for member_id then base the rest of the query off of associated friend_id's to display data accordingly to the right people. So with this logic of sorts in mind, that makes me think I would have to have 2 rows per request. One where its the member_id who's requesting and the friend_id of the request inserted into the table, then one thats the opposite so I could query accordingly every time. So in essences its like double dipping for every one action requested to this particular table I need to make 2 like actions to make it work.
Which in all does not make sense to me as far as optimization goes. So in all my question is what is the proper way to handle data for relations like this? Or am I actually thinking sanely about this being an approach to handling it?

Comment: Your first model works perfect. For the second part, finding both directions, there are many answers here already. Short Version: Build your SELECT query a bit fancyfull and you get both directions easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If a friendship is **always** mutual, then you can choose between data redundancy (i.e. both directions having a row) for the sake of simpler queries, or learn to live with slightly more complex queries. I'd personally avoid data redundancy unless there is a compelling reason otherwise - you're not just wasting space and performance, but you'll need to be careful when enforcing it - a simple CHECK is incapable of referencing other rows and depending on your DBMS a trigger may be limited in what it can do with a mutating table.

An easy way ensure to only one row per friendship is to always insert the lower value in `member_id` and higher value in `friend_id` (make a constraint `CHECK (member_id < friend_id)` to enforce it). Then, when you query, you'll have search in both directions - for example, finding all friends of the given person (identified by `person_id`) would look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM
    person
WHERE
    id <> :person_id
    AND (
        id IN (
            SELECT friend_id
            FROM friendship
            WHERE member_id = :person_id
        )
        OR
        id IN (
            SELECT member_id
            FROM friendship
            WHERE friend_id = :person_id
        )
    )
```

BTW, in this scheme, you'd probably want to rename `member_id` and `friend_id` to, say, `friend1_id` and `friend2_id`...

Comment: Just a note: using IN keyword in above code is not a good idea since it is not optimized in MySQL. In large tables, it may cause slow results.

Comment: @maliayas Yes, MySQL tends to under-optimize subqueries. Whether this is an actual problem in this particular case can only be determined by performing measurements on realistic amounts of data. My gut feeling is that there shouldn't be a performance problem here, but if I'm wrong then there are other ways to express essentially the same query, that can sidestep the MySQL's deficiency in this regard (e.g. JOIN).

Answer (score 5):

Two ways to look at it:

```
WHERE ((friend_id = x AND member_id = y) OR (friend_id = y AND member_id = x))
```

would allow you to query by simply stating one side of the relationship. If both sides are added, this method would still work without causing duplicate rows to be returned.

Conversely, adding both sides of the relationship, so that your queries consist of

```
WHERE friend_id = x AND member_id = y
```

not only makes queries easier to write, but also easier to plan (meaning better DB performance).

My vote is for the latter option.

Answer (score 1):

Beautiful - there's no problem with your table as-is.

ALSO:
I'm not sure if this cardinality is "one to many", or "many to many":

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29

> Q: I were to query I would typically query for member_id then base the
>   rest of the query off of associated friend_id's to display data
>   accordingly to the right people

A: Frankly, I don't see any problem querying "member to friend", or "friend to member" (or any other combinations - e.g. friends who share friends).  Again, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a helper table like:

```
users
user_id, name, ...

friendship
user_id, friend_id, ....

select u.name as user, u2.name as friend from users u
    inner join friendship f on f.user_id = u.user_id
    inner join users u2 on u2.user_id = f.friend_id
```

I think this is pretty similar to what you have, just putting a query as an example.

Comment: Potential duplicate entries if both sides of the relationship were added.

Comment: Not really if you see the name of the columns. It's a one way relationship, if both sides where added, two rows make sense.

Comment: The two row output complicates the join structure so that `GROUP BY` would need to be added in order to return a distinct set, as it would otherwise cause duplicates in the data joined to it.

Comment: If you query for one user to find his friends, you will only get ONE row of the relationship even if his friends friended him back. It depends on the semantics of the information you are trying to pull.